# Pole or removable singularity at infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

Let $f$ be an entire function such that the inverse image of the closed unit ball is bounded. State whether $\infty$ is a removable singularity or pole or essential singularity of $f$?

(I am familiar with the following two facts:
(1) $f$ has removable singularity at $\infty$ if and only if $f$ is constant.
(2) $f$ has a pole at infinity if and only if $f$ is polynomial.)

If $f$ is a constant function $c$ with $|c|>1$ then clearly $f$ has a removable singularity at $\infty$.

Now suppose $f$ is not constant. Then $f$ must have at most finietly many zeroes. But only this fact can't prove that $f$ is a polynomial. (For example $f(z)=ze^z$).

So how to show that $f$ is a polynomial?

Comment: Since the inverse image of closed unit disk of $f$ is bounded, $f$ cannot have essential singularity at $\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by Pythagorous uses a property of essential singularities. If you are not allowed to use that result you can use the following hint:

There exists $R$ such that $|z|>R$ implies $|f(z)| >1$. Let $z_1,z_2,...,z_n$ be the zeros of $f$ (counted according to mutiplicities) in $|z| \leq R$. Let $g=\frac  {(z-z_1)(z-z_2)...(z-z_n)} f$. The $g$ is entire and $|g(z)| \leq C|z|^{n}$ for $|z|>R$,  for some constant $C$. By a well know result (whose proof you can find on MSE) it follows that $g$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$. Can you finish?

Comment: $g$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$ we may write $g(z)=b_0+b_1z+\cdots+b_mz^m$ where $m\leq n$ . Then for $|z|>R$ we can write $f(z)=\frac{(z-z_1)(z-z_2)\cdots (z-z_n)}{b_0+b_1z+\cdots+b_mz^m}\\$ $=z^{n-m}\frac{(1-\frac{1}{z_1}\cdots(1-\frac{1}{z_n})}{\frac{b_0}{z^m}+\cdots+b_m}\\$ this will tend to infinity as $z$ goes to infinity. Hence $f$ has a pole at infinity

Comment: @ShreyaChauhan By definition of $g$ we already know that $f$ is a ratio of two polynomials. But $f$ is entire so it is a polynomial. Cancel the common factors between the numerator and the denominator. If the polynomial in the denominator is not a constant it will have at least one zero and then $f$ have a pole at that zero which is a contardictio. So the denominaor is a constant.

Comment: @ShreyaChauhan Be careful. You forgot about the case $n=m$.